# Why doesn't "Show" appear?

Tags: delphi, show-hide

In Delphi, I was going to make a button click show a form. From what I've seen, for every tutorial, there's a `Show` procedure in which it makes the other form show once the button is clicked. For me, however, this `Show` procedure does not appear and is considered as a "Undeclared Identifier" instead.

Here's the line of code I'm confused about:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Unit2.Show <= Doesnt exist for some reason????
end;
```

This is what other people did in tutorials, and I'm wondering what is wrong here? Why doesn't it appear? There's also `ShowModal` which doesn't appear as well. I'm confused. Is this a limitation of Community Edition, or what?

Comment: "This is what other people did in tutorials" Almost certainly not.

Answer (score 0):

A **unit** does not have a `Show(Modal)` method (or any method, for that matter).  A **Form** object does.  Make sure `Unit2` (or whatever unit is implementing your Form) is in your `uses` clause, and then change `Unit2.Show` to `Form2.Show` (or whatever your Form object is actually named), eg:

```
uses
  ..., Unit2;

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Of course, make sure the Form object has actually been created before you try to call methods on it.  In your project options, you can set a Form to be auto-created at program startup.  Otherwise, you will have to `Create()` it in code yourself.

Comment: that was quick, man thanks. you re right, in the tutorials i saw i didnt pay attention to that and assumed it wasnt important, THX